# E/SQLiteLog(2082): (1) near "Security": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to using SQLite so structuring the select query is what I think is the problem.

Anyway, I'm trying to get a statement prepared that will give me the module name, module lecture time and module seminar time depending on what the current day is (which is determined in `MainActivity`)

Below is the method to return the list 
**getModuleTime**

```
public List<tableModules> getModuleTime(String module1, String module2, String module3, String day) {
    List<tableModules> moduleList = new ArrayList<tableModules>();
    // Select All Query     
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT modulename, modulelecturetime, moduleseminartime FROM " + Table2 + " WHERE modulename=? OR modulename=? OR modulename=? AND WHERE modulelecturedate=? OR moduleseminardate=?", new String[]{module1, module2, module3, day, day});  
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            tableModules module = new tableModules();
            module.modulename = cursor.getString(1);
            module.modulelecturedate = cursor.getString(2);
            module.moduleseminardate = cursor.getString(3);
            moduleList.add(module);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return contact list
    return moduleList;      
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
02-23 01:18:27.177: E/SQLiteLog(3050): (1) near "WHERE": syntax error
02-23 01:18:27.192: D/AndroidRuntime(3050): Shutting down VM
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050): Process: com.example.project, PID: 3050
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.project/com.example.project.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT modulename, modulelecturetime, moduleseminartime FROM Modules WHERE modulename=? OR modulename=? OR modulename=? AND WHERE modulelecturedate=? OR moduleseminardate=?
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3020)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT modulename, modulelecturetime, moduleseminartime FROM Modules WHERE modulename=? OR modulename=? OR modulename=? AND WHERE modulelecturedate=? OR moduleseminardate=?
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at com.example.project.DB.getModuleTime(DB.java:134)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at com.example.project.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:106)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6076)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2978)
02-23 01:18:27.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3050):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You need quotes (') around Digital Security, so 'Digital Security'

Comment: It's called from the database though depending on who is logged in

Comment: Or do you mean on the database insert for digital security add in quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL has 3 errors.

1)You need to put your string constants in quotes-  'DIGITAL SECURITY'

2)Your where clause is wrong.  It isn't "WHERE x= 7 OR 10 OR 11".  Its "WHERE x=7 OR x=10 OR x=11".

3)The second half is also wrong.  You can't go "foo OR bar =7" you need to go "foo=7 OR bar=7"

Comment: Thankyou, I was unsure about the SQL I will change it now. Also Digital Security was pulled from the database, do I edit it inside the db class where it is inserted?

Comment: The best way to do it is a bind variable.  "WHERE x=?".  Then you can supply ? when you run the query.  This allows the db to optimize by preparing the statement and prevents SQL injection bugs.

Comment: What if I removed all the whitespace from my database inserts? would that also prevent the error

Comment: It would, but you should still use bind variables.  Its just good practice-  if that data was ever entered by a user, they could make it an SQL command and screw up your database.  Anything that isn't hardcoded to an exact value should almost always be bound.

Comment: I have rewritten the statement, i will update the code now